# text processing - Append next line with previous until the lines ends with "^"

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

I have a text file which contains data in the below format.

```
1^0^this is test file line1^
2^1^this is test file line2^
3^1^this
is
test
file line3^
4^1^this
is
file line4^
```

until the next line ends with ^, it need to append with previous line

Output:

```
1^0^this is test file line1^
2^1^this is test file line2^
3^1^this is test file line3^
4^1^this is file line4^
```

Comment: line3 and line4 end with `^`, is the input correct?

Comment: i will correct the question title, i want the result as per the output mentioned above

Comment: Why are line 2 and line 3 not appended to line1?

Comment: i have corrected the input and output now.

Answer (score 3):

Manipulate the value of output record separator (`ORS`) according to line endings.

```sh
$ awk '{ORS=/\^$/?"\n":" "}1' file
1^0^this is test file line1^
2^1^this is test file line2^
3^1^this is test file line3^
4^1^this is file line4^
```

Answer (score 0):

A cheap and easy bash script.  Rather than look for the trailing carrot, it looks for the leading number and carrot.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$HOME/asdf.txt
prevLine=""
while IFS= read -r var
do
    if [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]{1}\^.*$ ]]
    then
        echo "$prevLine"
        prevLine=""
        prevLine="$var"
    else
        prevLine+=" $var"
    fi
done < "$filename"
echo "$prevLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed 4.2 (support -z option), you can use

```
sed -rz 's/([^^])\n/\1/g' file
```

With an older `sed` you can use

```
tr "\n" "\r" < file | sed -r 's/([^^])\r/\1/g' | tr "\r" "\n"
```

EDIT: When you want spaces between joined lines, use

```
sed -rz 's/([^^])\n/\1 /g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed one, using the little-known hold space:

```
$ sed -ne '/[^^]$/{H;d}; {H;g;s/\n/ /g;p;s/.*//;h}' test.txt; 
^1^0^this is test file line1^
^2^1^this is test file line2^
^3^1^this is test file line3^
^4^1^this is file line4^
```

Basically: If the current line (*pattern space*) doesn't end in ^, append it to the *hold space* and go on to the next line. Otherwise, again append the current line to the hold space, then replace the current pattern space with the hold space, deal with the newlines added by `H`, and print the result. Then empty out the hold space in preparation for the next sequence of lines (Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a really easy to do this last bit in one step)

Notes:

- This will have issues if the last line of input doesn't end in a ^.
- If using GNU sed, replace the `s/.*//` with `z`.